# Do I need Python installed if I have PYC files?

Tags: python

I want to add Python as a scripting language to my game. If instead of distributing PY script, I distribute the PYC compiled files with my game, will the user still need Python installed, or will the DLL be sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only would they still need the Python interpreter, but the compiled python byte-code files are not guaranteed to work across different platforms.

Comment: By "the compiled python byte-code files are not guaranteed to work across different platforms" do you mean that they might not work from computer to computer, or from Windows to Linux, for example?

Comment: I believe the bytecode *is* actually relatively safe across platforms, but I think you should only really consider this if you are targeting an exact processor/platform like an embedded system. It certainly isn't safe across different versions of python, so you still need to ensure they have the same Python running the files anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You do need an executable to actually *load* the files into the VM. Fortunately it [doesn't need to be very complex](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html).

Comment: This isn't really what I asked. :P

Comment: If you want a direct answer, then "No, the end user will not need to have Python installed. But just the DLL will not be enough.".

Answer (score 0):

pyinstaller can be used to convert the .py file into an executable file

to install the pyinstaller

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

and to convert the .py file let's say file.py

```
pyinstaller file.py
```

this will make two new folders in the same directory 
build and dist. dist folder contains all the required dll and file.exe to run the python code without python installed.